# Javascript popup

Tags: javascript, validation

I have this validation

```
box = $("#lessthan5");
        if (box.prop("checked") == false) {
            box = document.getElementById("hours");
            if(box.value =='' ){
                alert("Please enter a value for Hours.")
                box.focus()
                return false;
            }
            if( !IsNumeric(box.value)  ){
                alert("Please enter numbers only for Hours.")
                box.focus()
                return false;
            } else if( parseFloat(box.value) == 0.0 ){
                alert("Please enter a non-zero amount for Hours.")
                box.focus()
                return false;
            }
```

How do i make it so if a user inputs the number 5.00 an alert will pop up saying are you sure this is correct, and if they say yes proceed if cancel then don't proceed.

Comment: you can use JavaScript confirm('confirmation text'); or jQuery dialog

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for `confirm()`. For example:

```
var proceed = confirm('Are you sure?');
```

`proceed` will then be `true` if accepted or `false` if cancelled.

Comment: But given the code I have ,how will It exactly work to appear if the user types the number 5.00? can u carry on from the code I provided above?